# Uninstall Lua from OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos

I was browsing the Lua source code and I did "make install". It worked perfectly but I could not uninstall it! How can I install Lua 5.0?

Comment: Why can't you uninstall it?  What happens if you `make uninstall`?

Comment: @Ken it says that there is not a target for uninstall

Comment: Weird, I guess they only added uninstall in version 5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of Lua 5.0's makefile, I'd say:

1. Run `make echo`, and note the folders `INSTALL_BIN`, `INSTALL_INC`, `INSTALL_LIB`, and `INSTALL_MAN`
2. For each file in `bin`, remove that file from `INSTALL_BIN`
3. For each file in `include` named `*.h`, remove that file from `INSTALL_INC`
4. For each file in `lib` named `*.a`, remove that file from `INCLUDE_LIB`
5. For each file in `doc` named `*.1`, remove that file from `INCLUDE_MAN`
6. Upgrade to Lua 5.2 so if you accidentally install again, you can uninstall  :-)

**Alternatively**: if you download Lua 5.2 and configure it in exactly the same way (so all the INSTALL_* folders are the same), then its `make uninstall` will delete almost all of these for you.  You only have to delete `liblualib.a` from `INCLUDE_LIB`.